# How to send headers after loop

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to do find an user, whose model contains an array of cities (for example:[Madrid, London, Moscow, Buenos Aires, etc])

This is the model:

```
var UserSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    userName: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    rol: String,
    suscriptionDate: Date,
    cities:[String],
    citiesPopulate:[]
});
```

Once I've found the user, I want to iterate through this array to use each city as the parameter in order to find the info that I have on the model City just to add coords to user.citiesPopulate

```
function findUsersCities(req,res){
    let id=req.body._id;

    User.findById(id,function(err,userFound){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{

            for(let i=0;i<userFound.cities.length;i++){

                City.findOne({'city':userFound.cities[i]},function(err,citiesFound){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }else{
                        userFound.citiesPopulate.push(citiesFound.coords);
                        console.log(userFound)
                    }
                })
            } 

        }
    })
}
```

And, once all the info of every single city has been added to userFound.citiesPopulate (by now just arrays with a pair of coordinates), I want to use *res.status(200).send({userFound})* to see the result on my postman console, something like this(three cities and three pairs of coordinates):

```
{ cities: [ 'Bilbao', 'Madrid', 'Barcelona' ],
  citiesPopulate: [ [ -3.68, 40.4 ], [ -2.97, 43.25 ], [ 2.18, 41.38 ] ],
  _id: 5c82c2e5cfa8d543d0133dd6,
  name: 'pruebas35',
  surname: 'pruebas35',
  userName: 'pruebas35',
  email: 'pruebas35@prueba.es',
  password: '$2a$10$eSue5gw7r4dFPtwD8qzJhODcvvNFaRkeQYRAOPO9MCBsy3Djhkffq',
  rol: 'user',
  suscriptionDate: 2019-03-08T19:30:45.075Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

But if I type the *res.status* into the loop, it is sent and I can´t get the whole information.

I'd like to know a solution for this, please.

Comment: If I use a callback function after the first query, the one that finds the user by Id, I get an error that says:TypeError: Invalid select() argument. Must be string or object. But the argument is actually a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Carlos, this won't work because of the asynchronous nature of database requests. The way I would do it is to use async/await to make the code synchronous, like this:

```
function findUsersCities(req,res){
    let id=req.body._id;

    User.findById(id,async function(err,userFound){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            try {

                for(let i=0;i<userFound.cities.length;i++){

                    let cityFound = await City.findOne({'city':userFound.cities[i]});

                    userFound.citiesPopulate.push(cityFound.coords);
                }

                //complete userFound
                console.log(userFound);

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Notice the use of the keyword `async` in the callback function from `User.findById`. You can only use the `await` feature if it is inside a function marked with the async keyword.

Also, when you doesn't specify a callback function to any Mongoose query funcion, it returns a Promise, and you can only use the await keyword on promises.

If the promise resolves, the code will continue to run, and the resolved value will be in the variable `cityFound`, otherwise (if the promise rejects), it will throw an execption, so the code will fall into the catch statement, and the rejected value will be in variable `e`.

Comment: This is what I did first but the problem is that it returns the coords array empty as this is asynchronus, and it deals faster with res.status(200).send({userFound}) rather than the for loop, I guess

Comment: You are correct, my apologies. Edited the answer, check if it helps you now.