# how to save multiple for loops data?

Tags: mongodb, api, express, mongoose-schema

In Post request, I want to pull objectId's data and save it in the database. There will be 2 or 3 objectId's which will I will be getting it in array. From that array I am able to pull the data with separate "for loops" but at the end I am not able to save the data. 
I want to know how to move data from one array to another or directly save the data.

Schema:--

```
const jobSch = new Schema({
    token : {type:Number},
    name : {type:String},
    phoneNumber: {type:Number},
    gender : {type:String},
    stage : {type:String},
    categoryId : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    subCategoryId : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    serviceId : [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    category : [String],
    subcategory : [String],
    service: [String],
    paymenttype: [String],
    tax: {type:Number},
    totalprice: {type:String},
    servicePerson: {type:String},
    createdOn : {type:Date, default:new Date()},
    updatedOn : {type:Date, default:new Date()}   
});
```

POST request code:--

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    let ids = req.body;
    let catId = ids.categoryId;
    console.log("catId", catId)
    console.log("catId.length", catId.length)
    let subcatId = ids.subCategoryId;
    console.log("subcatId", subcatId);
    console.log("subcatId.length", subcatId.length)
    let serId = ids.serviceId;
    console.log("serId", serId);
    console.log("subcatId.length", serId.length)
    let job = new Job(ids);
    let catgy=[];
    let subcatgy=[];
    let subser=[];

    for (i = 0; i < catId.length; i++) {
        Category.findById(catId[i])
            .then(category => {
                if (category && category != null) {
                    console.log('category.name', category.name);
                    catgy.push(`${category.name}`)
                    console.log(catgy);

                }
            })
    }
    for (i = 0; i < subcatId.length; i++) {
        Service.findById(subcatId[i])
            .then(service => {
                if (service && service != null) {
                    console.log('service.name', service.name);
                    subcatgy.push(`${service.name}`)
                    console.log(subcatgy);

                }
            })
    }
    for (i = 0; i < serId.length; i++) {
        Subservice.findById(serId[i])
            .then(subService => {
                if (subService && subService != null) {
                    console.log('subservice.name', subService.subService);
                    subser.push(`${subService.subService}`)
                  console.log(subser);
                }
            })
    }
    var category = catgy.slice();
    console.log("category1", category)
    var service = subcatgy.slice();
    console.log('service2', service);
    var subService = subser.slice();
    console.log('subService3',subService);
    console.log(job);
    job.save().then(job => {
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Job saved successfully', job
        })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: i got a different solution for pushing the data.. But thanks the link which u had give gave me a rough idea!!! @RenatoVassao

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the callback function of the resolved promises (`findById`) are executed asynchronously. Try checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071803/how-to-send-headers-after-loop/55072166) out, I think it will help you.